# Forcing Windows 10 Onscreen keyboard to display at login

Tags: windows, group-policy

I've got tablets (Ava mobile Inari 10's, they're somewhat hardened and water/dust resitant) tablets to deploy which will live in a dock 90% of the time.  These are POS devices, and the user has no keyboard and will use the tablet's Point of Sale app virtually 100% of the time.  However, for login to the device, we'd like the user to be able to use the Windows 10 On-screen Keyboard to login.

I've tried EVERYTHING, but when a device is in the dock, the Windows 10 OSK just does not appear.  The Windows Pin entry pad works.  A USB keyboard works, but tapping on the password box will not launch the OSK.

*Here's the weird part:* as soon as I remove the tablet from the dock, the on-screen keyboard immediately appears.

We're using fully patched Windows 10 2016 LTSB as the OS, has anyone else run into this?

I've set the `Windows Ink and Handwriting Recognition` service to Auto-start and can confirm that the OSK appears when not docked.  However, as soon as the device goes into the dock, the OSK is dismissed and cannot be relaunched.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In cosmic irony, of course as soon as you post a thread on StackExchange, you find the answer to your problems.

If you'd like to force the OSK to be available at login, set the following registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl]
 "ConvertibleSlateMode"=dword:00000000
```

You will need to take ownership of the key and lock permissions to ensure that Windows does not overwrite the key, but after that, you'll have the OSK available at login!

Comment: Here more about the "ConvertibleSlateMode" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-gpiobuttons-convertibleslatemode